# What is the use of these keyword in sql server (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK READPAST)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i like to know what is the use of these keyword in sql server `(UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK READPAST)` and when to use it? i mean in what kind of situation people go for `(UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK READPAST)`.

```
1) select top 1 COMMAND
from EXAMPLE_TABLE
with (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
where PROCESSED=false;
```

just see the above sql they use `UPDLOCK`, `ROWLOCK` what is `UPDLOCK`, `ROWLOCK`?

what will happen for `UPDLOCK`, `ROWLOCK` ?

```
2) SELECT TOP(1) COMMAND, PROCESSED
  FROM TABLE WITH (READPAST)
  WHERE PROCESSED = 0
```

what is `READPAST`? when we use `READPAST` then what happen ?

```
3) UPDATE  OrderTable WITH ( ROWLOCK )
    SET     ProcessorID = @PROCID
    WHERE   OrderID IN ( SELECT TOP ( 20 )
                                        OrderID
                                FROM    OrderTable WITH ( ROWLOCK )
                                WHERE   ProcessorID = 0)
```

here the above sql use `ROWLOCK` for update statement and also in nested select sub query......why??

what will happen for `ROWLOCK` ?

it is my request that please explain each point with lots of example in such way as a result i can understand the usage of those keyword. thanks

Comment: what does the documentation say that you don't understand?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not include a particular question or problem, but rather asks broad general questions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They are (`DML`) statements for specifying a locking method:

`UPDLOCK` places update locks on rows that are being selected until the end of the transaction.
Other transaction cannot update or delete the row but they are allowed to select it.

`ROWLOCK` places locks on row level opposed to a page or table lock.

`READPAST` Records that are locked are not returned

This is an example of using both statements, meaning that other transaction cannot read update or delete data until the first transaction ends.

```
BEGIN TRAN

  select top 1 COMMAND
  from EXAMPLE_TABLE
  with (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
  where PROCESSED=false;

ROLLBACK
```

Here the transaction has not ended:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

      UPDATE TOP(1) EXAMPLE_TABLE
      SET colum1 = colum1 + 1
```

If you execute a select statement records that are locked are not returned, example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WITH(READPAST)
```

Comment: u did not mention or explain the usage of READPAST ??

Comment: see the edit above :)